# Where has an image been dropped with fineuploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

Is it possible to know where an image has been dropped?
Assume we have a checkerboard with different divs

```
<div id="jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader"></div>

<div id="checkerboard">
<div id="A1" class="ffup"></div>
<div id="A2" class="ffup"></div>
<div id="A3" class="ffup"></div>
<div id="A4" class="ffup"></div>
......

</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: 'endpoint.php'
        },
        dragAndDrop: {
            extraDropzones: [$('.ffup')]
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would like know in which div-id the new image has been dropped. Then on the server side I would like to save the image-ref into the database. Best would be to send the div-id with the image to the server side script as a additional param

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code will only designate the first ffup div (A1) as it currently stands.  You will need to pass a selector for each individual drop zone into your `extraDropzones` array.  The jQuery wrapper will only pass the first element covered by your jQuery selector to the library.  Ideally, it would pass along all items represented by the selector, but, to do this, it would have to be aware of the intended type of the parameter.  The jQuery wrapper must convert all jQuery objects to HTMLElements before passing the data on to Fine Uploader's core code (which is not aware of jQuery).  This is something I'd like to look into more in the future, but this is the way it has worked since 3.0.  Note that this limitation does NOT apply to the target of a Fine Uploader plug-in instance, i.e. `$(".myTarget").fineUploader(...)`.

As to your question, Fine Uploader does not currently pass any information along to callbacks that would allow you to determine which drop zone received an associated file.  This is an interesting feature, and I can see how it may be useful.  Please [open up a feature request in the issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new) so we can discuss and prioritize this for a future release.